# Javascript/CouchDB controlling user login logout

Tags: javascript, forms, authentication, couchdb

I'm struggling to grasp the concept of the best way to implement a user login/logout with JavaScript and CouchDB.

I'm used to creating user login/logout control using server side code that creates a session storing the user info and then automatically runs code on the secured pages to "lock out" unauthorized users.

Of course this same setup is not possible with client side code. I've read a lot about different "concepts" - be it HTTP Basic Auth, Cookie Authentication, or third party providers like OAuth, Persona, or OpenID.

So imagine - My user loads the login form in his browser (HTTPS of course) > he enters his credentials in the form and submits > javascript then validates the credentials against those stored in CouchDB using a REST call > login is successful > HERE IS WHERE IT GETS FUZZY FOR ME...

Normally I would then store the user info in a session var and the server would handle the auth. With JavaScript do I have to use a cookie then? Obviously I don't store the username and password in the cookie, especially not in clear text, do I have to generate a token, hash the token and store it in the cookie and database? Then on every page that is "secured" do I have to have a script that checks for that cookie/token? When the user logs out then you remove the cookie and token?

Please let me know if I'm understanding this correctly or not, is there a better way to go about this? Can I implement some kind of security using CouchDB? I kind of hate storing anything in a cookie, but maybe it's the only way with JavaScript? Thanks!!!!!

Comment: Checkout the test suite that ships with Futon (the web-based admin UI).  On my older CouchDB install, it is here: http://localhost:5984/_utils/script/test/cookie_auth.js

Comment: I will do that, I was dreading having to "roll my own" so to speak. Hopefully this will give me the best practices at least with CouchDB. Thanks!!!!

Comment: This page also seems to have a lot of good info on the subject: http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/security.html

Comment: If you get stuck, the CouchDB devs hang out on IRC and have answered my questions before.  It is helpful and humbling at the same time.